# How to use .Net Standard 2.0 DbContext in .Net Core and .Net Framework application?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, .net-standard

I have a class library targetting .NET Standard 2.0 which has a `DbContext` with these constructor parameters:

```
public SqlSettings _sqlSettings;         
 
public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options, IOptions<SqlSettings> sqlSettings) : base(options)
{
    _sqlSettings = sqlSettings.Value;
}

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{              
    optionsBuilder.UseMySQL(_sqlSettings.ConnectionString);          
}
```

I can use this in a .NET Core application using service configuration but not sure how I can use or create the context to access the database in the .NET Framework 4.7 application.

Comment: .NET Framework 4.7.2 or later fully support .NET Standard 2.0

Comment: Thanks for the comment, My problem is using same in .Net Framework.